# Pandas: adjust value of DataFrame that is sliced multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Imagine I have the follow Pandas.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  
})
```

I want to adjust the first `value` when `type == 'B'` to 999, i.e. the fourth row's `value` should become 999.

Initially I imagined that

```
df.loc[df['type'] == 'B'].iloc[0, -1] = 999
```

or something similar would work. But as far as I can see, slicing the `df` twice does not point to the original `df` anymore so the value of the `df` is not updated.

My other attempt is

```
df.loc[df.loc[df['type'] == 'B'].index[0], df.columns[-1]] = 999
```

which works, but is quite ugly.

So I'm wondering -- what would be the best approach in such situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) which returns the index of the first occurrence of a max value. Like this using a boolean series:

```
df.loc[(df['type'] == 'B').idxmax(), 'value'] = 999
```

Output:

```
   type  value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3
3    B    999
4    B      5
5    B      6
```